# JAXRSClientFactory not found in cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.0

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, cxf-client

I was using `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactory` to create a REST client out of a properly annotated interface.

However, I needed to update the `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs` version from `2.7.18` to `3.3.0` since somewhere else in my code `WebApplicationException` is used and that starts to throw compilation errors for the version `2.7.18`.

However, after updating to `3.3.0` , which is the latest version, the `client` package itself has disappeared from the `jaxrs` package.

Can anyone please tell me where can I locate the `JAXRSClientFactory` in the new jar. Meseems it has been removed altogether.

Answer (score 2):

My bad.

It seems they have moved this package to this new artifact [cxf-rt-rs-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-client/3.3.0)